# TSQL - Window function / Ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find all people that missed 3 or more consecutive appointments. I believe I can use a windowing function to accomplish this, but I am stuck and looking for some help.

Here is a sample of what I am looking for:
For the following PATID = x001 meets the criteria for missing 1/12,1/14,1/15
And PATID = x002 Will not meet the criteria.

```
PATID  DEPT   DATE       STATUS
x001   A002   1/1/2016   Missed
x001   A002   1/5/2016   Complete
x001   A002   1/8/2016   Missed
x001   A002   1/10/2016   Complete
x001   A002   1/12/2016   Missed
x001   A002   1/14/2016   Missed
x001   A002   1/15/2016   Missed
x001   A002   1/19/2016   Complete

x002   A003   1/1/2016   Missed
x002   A003   1/5/2016   Complete
x002   A003   1/8/2016   Missed
x002   A003   1/10/2016   Complete
x002   A003   1/12/2016   Missed
x002   A003   1/14/2016   Complete
x002   A003   1/15/2016   Missed
x002   A003   1/19/2016   Complete
```

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
PR.PATID
, PR.DEPT
, PR.DATE
, CASE WHEN PR.STATUS IN (3,4) THEN 'Cancel' WHEN PR.STATUS = 2 THEN 'COMPLETED' ELSE 'ERROR' END AS STATUS, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PR.PAT_ID,PR.DEPARTMENT_ID ORDER BY R.PAT_ID,PR.DEPARTMENT_ID,PR.CONTACT_DATE) AS RN  -- Just numbers the rows
, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PR.PAT_ID,PR.DEPARTMENT_ID, CASE WHEN PR.APPT_STATUS_C IN (3,4) AND PR.CANCEL_REASON_C <> 4 THEN 'Cancel'                  WHEN PR.APPT_STATUS_C = 2 THEN 'COMPLETED' ELSE 'ERROR' END) AS RNC  -- Should have break at new statuses
FROM #PatsReturn AS PR
```

Once I figure out how to assign the correct breaks at the new status changes by dates, then I need to figure out a way to identify (possibly a new flag field??) the PATIDs that have missed 3+ consecutive....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

One method is just to use `lag()`/`lead()`:

```
select distinct patid
from (select pr.*,
             lead(status) over (partition by patid order by date) as status_1,
             lead(status, 2) over (partition by patid order by date) as status_2
      from #PatsReturn pr
     ) pr
where status = 'Missed' and status_1 = 'Missed' and status_2 = 'Missed';
```

If you want information about each sequence, you can identify groups of similar appointments.  One method is a difference of row numbers:

```
select patid, count(*) as numMissed, min(date), max(date)
from (select pr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by patid order by date) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (partition by patid, status order by date) as seqnum_ps
      from #PatsReturn pr
     ) pr
where status = 'Missed'
group by patid, (seqnum_p - seqnum_ps)
having count(*) >= 3;
```

To understand how this works, run the subquery and you can see the pattern where the difference in the two "seqnum" values is constant for sequences of the same status.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with Gordon's first solution you will want a POC index. Say this is your table:

```
CREATE TABLE #PatsReturn (PATID char(4), DEPT char(4), [date] date, [status] varchar(10));
```

You would want this index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nc_PatsReturn  ON #PatsReturn(PATID, [date]) INCLUDE ([status]);
```

This will ensure a nice, linear sort-free query execution plan. The second solution would be a little trickier to index for.